# Android room db migration delete from table all embedded columns

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, database-migration

I trying to delete "@Embedded" object from some table by

```
class MigrateFrom28To29 : AutoMigrationSpec
```

example:

```
@Entity
data class A(
   @PrimaryKey var a: String,
   var b: String,
   @Embedded(prefix = "c_") var c: C
)

data class C (
    val a: String,
    val b: String,
    val c: String,
): Serializable
```

To my migration class I add annotations:

```
@DeleteColumn(tableName = "A", columnName = "c_a")
@DeleteColumn(tableName = "A", columnName = "c_b")
@DeleteColumn(tableName = "A", columnName = "c_c")
class MigrateFrom28To29 : AutoMigrationSpec
```

Any simple way to do it (not add each member to DeleteColumn) when C class is complex and has a lot of members?